# What exactly do Stopself()? What's the best way to terminate a service running?

Tags: java, android, service

i'm a beginner in android and have not much experience on java...

I have an Activity that creates an `ALARM MANAGER` and starts `alarmManager.setRepeating()` pointing to a Service.

This Service in onCreate set a partial wakelock to perform the entire execution of the code (the app is made for non user interaction an so the phone is always in standby).

All of this work perfect.

Sometimes the Service should not perform entire code, but exit before from execution. So i have used  `StopSelf` but i have some doubts:

- `onDestroy` function in Service has the code to delete the wakelock. Does `StopSelf()` call it?
- Anyway if i don't specify any function to terminate the service, after code execution when is it terminated?

So in my case, is better replace `onDestroy()` instead of `Stopself()` ? 
many thanx!

Comment: Why don't you use a logoutput in onDestroy to see if it is executed, after you call stopself? Would you mind posting some of your Service-Code? That would definately help us help you ;)

Comment: Thanx man, i'm doing this now, but i'm not at home and so i can't test the code.. :-)

Comment: I'had not post the code because is too long :-(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should call `stopSelf ()` to stop a service. After you call it, the Android Framework will call `onDestroy()` method automatically.

Actually, these onXXX() methods(the prefix "on" implies that these methods are callbacks for the system) should be called by the system, not the developers.
Read the SDK [document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

`stopSelf()` is called before the `Thread` finishes.
The `Thread` runs to completion when `stopSelf()` is called.

`Service` is still destroyed at the point of the `stopSelf()` call.

Comment: Thanx friend, i'm very ignorant about these things. But without stopself() when the service is destroyed? (and so, wakelock deleted) Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your other question the service only terminates in case stopSelf() or Context.stopService() is called.

Reference:
Go to Service Lifecycle in: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Answer (score 0):

Stop the service, if it was previously started.